# Get special chars from $_GET

Tags: php, get

I have a list that looks like "1, 2" and so on.
When I send this list with $_GET the browser shows this in the address bar: `?myList=1,%25202`.

The problem is that that's what I get in PHP. I'd like to explode the list based on "`,` " (notice the space after the comma) but I can't do that since it gets formatted another way. How can I explode the list anyway? I need to end up with an array containing all the element in the list and the elements are separated by a comma followed by a space.

`explode(", ", $list);` just doesn't work.

Thanks!

EDIT: this is passed inside of a GET request like this:

```
$args = "list=" . $_POST["assigned"];
$extra = 'test.php?' . $args;
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
```

---

```
$s = "1,%25202";
$p = explode(", ", urldecode($s));
var_dump($p);
```

result:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "1,%202" }
```

---

```
$s = "1,%25202";
$p = explode(", ", base64_decode($s));
var_dump($p);
```

result:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "�nv�" }
```

Comment: What about trying explode(", ", urldecode($list));

Comment: Your string is double-encoded. Calling `urldecode` on it (as PHP will do automatically) gets `'%202'`, which can then be decoded again to `' 2'`. Work out why the string is getting URL-encoded twice, and stop it happening.

Comment: How are you placing the value into a URL parameter? If it is correctly encoded on the way in, it will correctly decode _automatically_ on the way out.

Comment: it is actually a parameter which was in a POST request previously - from the POST request I build the GET url. Should I do something to the POST before submitting?

Comment: @Saturnix You'll need to post the code where that transfer from `POST` to `GET` occurs. Under normal circumstances, the value in `$_POST` will be automatically decoded when you pass it to `$_GET`, but something has prevented that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try:

```
   $numbers = urldecode($_GET['key']);
```

Then explode `$numbers.`

If the browsers automatically encoding them as safe characters then you'll need to decode them.

Answer (score 0):

Something's happening all the way at the beginning of your script, in the `POST` variable. Here's a quick proof-of-concept that validates that if your variable really is `1, 2`, it will decode correctly:

```
if(empty($_GET['myList'])) {
    $simulated_POST = '1, 2';

    $extra = http_build_query(array(
        'myList' => $simulated_POST
    ));

    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?' . $extra);

} else {
    $myList = explode(', ', $_GET['myList']);
    var_dump($myList);

}
```

Can you validate that the `POST` variable is indeed `1, 2` when it's sent?

Comment: thanks for posting. Not working, unfortunately :( - check updated question

Comment: Revised example for you to play with -- @lonesomeday is correct that the POST variable is double-encoded.